# AWS ECR stable tags - ECS does not pull new images

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

We use stable tags for our docker images, meaning an image with version tag "1.2" is pushed to ECR. If we do not touch the code itself but doing updates (e. g. packages), we push the image again with version tag "1.2.". The old image gets untagged, the new image gets the tag. So far, so good.

In ECS task definition, we are pointing to version tag "1.2". But when a new task is created or a rolling update should be executed, the new image is not pulled. It is pulled only if we use the digest or we really change the tag, e. g. to "1.2.1". Thats not how it should work, correct? Or how are you dealing with this topic?

Answer (score 0):

The ECS EC2 instances will cache the images. The only way to truly make sure that the new image is always pulled, is to change the image tag each time.  I highly recommend [enabling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-tag-mutability.html) Immutable Image Tags on your ECR repositories and changing your workflow to always create a new image tag.